# Ignore captial word at beginning of line, replace others with regex?

Tags: python, regex, capitalization

Basically I am trying to turn the following line:

```
TILL: LOOK we've got like a new bOArd
```

into this:

```
TILL: <emph>look</emph> we've got like a new b<emph>oa</emph>rd
```

(The capitalized name at the beginning of the line should stay that way)

using this code:

```
line = re.sub('(:[^A-Z]*) *([A-Z]+)', r'\1<emph>\L\2</emph>', line)
```

But I get a "bad escape" error for the /L and it ignores the second emphasis.
Does anybody have any ideas for solving this?

Comment: while it might be possible to do this with a regex, why cant you do this 'manually' with code?  the error you're getting is simple enough though: \L is not a valid escape , what do you hope it would do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `(:[^A-Z]*) *([A-Z]+)` will not match `bOArd` further down the line as there are other chars in between which are not matched by the second capture group `([A-Z]+)` only.

But if that group would match the rest of the line, you would still have to match the uppercase chars separately from that group again to place them between `<emph></emph>` tags.

---

You might use a pattern to capture the pattern at the start in group 1 and in the callback of re.sub check if it exists.

If it does exists, leave it unmodified. If it does not exist, replace it with the match between `<emph></emph>` tags.

In the callback use `.lower()` to turn the uppercase chars into lowercase chars.

```
^([A-Z]+:)|[A-Z]+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z]+:)` Capture group 1, match 1 or more uppercase chars A-Z followed by `:`
- `|`
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1 or more uppercase chars A-Z

See s [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qpb3Jl/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0DlTDF).

```
import re

pattern = r"^([A-Z]+:)|[A-Z]+"
s = r"TILL: LOOK we've got like a new bOArd"

result = re.sub(
    pattern,
    lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "<emph>{0}</emph>".format(x.group().lower()),
    s
)

print(result)
```

Output

```
TILL: <emph>look</emph> we've got like a new b<emph>oa</emph>rd
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
import re

text = "TILL: LOOK we've got like a new bOArd"

s = []

for word in text.split():
    if re.search(r'([A-Z]{1,}:?)', word):
        if ':' not in word:
            word = re.sub('([A-Z]{1,})', r'<emph>\1</emph>', word)
            word = word.lower()
    s.append(''.join(word))

s = ' '.join(s)
print(s)
```

**Outputs:**

```
TILL: <emph>look</emph> we've got like a new b<emph>oa</emph>rd
```

To always skip the first word and freeing up the regex, try:

```
import re

text = "TILL: LOOK we've got like a new bOArd"

s = []

for i, word in enumerate(text.split()):
    if i > 0:
        if re.search(r'([A-Z]{1,})', word):
            word = re.sub('([A-Z]{1,})', r'<emph>\1</emph>', word)
            word = word.lower()
    s.append(''.join(word))

s = ' '.join(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
line='TILL: LOOK we\'ve got like a new bOArd'
print(line)
line = re.sub('(:[^A-Z]*) *([A-Z]+)', r'\1<emph>\2</emph>', line)
capitalized_words = r"((?:[A-Z]+ ?)+)"
m = (re.findall(capitalized_words, line))
line = re.sub(m[1],m[1].lower(),line)
print(line)
```

O/p:
TILL: LOOK we've got like a new bOArd
['TILL', 'LOOK', 'OA']
TILL: look we've got like a new bOArd